# Database or list of romanized Chinese names and last names?

Tags: data-request, names

Is there any easily accessible datasource where I can find a complete list of romanized Chinese given names and family names?

I tried using [Searching for list(s) of babynames containing huge (10k+) amounts of unique names](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/searching-for-lists-of-babynames-containing-huge-10k-amounts-of-unique-name/4757#4757) but unfortunately it only provides an accessible source for gender of names, not nationality which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin) is a wide-spread Romanization system for Chinese words. [The Comprehensive Database of Chinese Name Variants](http://www.cjk.org/cjk/samples/cnamevar.htm) is a repository of Chinese names and their various Romanized counterparts. According to their website, the database contains "over 1,650,000 Chinese seed names (surnames and given names) and approximately five million romanized variants for these names."[image]

Comment: This is a paid for service, not open data.