# Name and gender dataset

Tags: data-request

Looking for an name/gender dataset. From first name I need to infere whether it is a male or female. There are many online service, like [this](https://gender-api.com), or [this](https://genderize.io). I need JSON or XML, to store it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answers ([one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5003/1511) & [two](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4757/1511)) on given names and country of origin also has gender guesses.

The file is a little cryptic, but it's the most complete dataset that's openly available.

> The best source of international human given (first) names comes from a German computer magazine. The text file has nearly 50k names that are classified by likely gender, and how popular in each country. It's carefully curated and has a friendly license (GNU Free Documentation License).
>
> The file can be downloaded here : ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ct/listings/0717-182.zip (name_dict.txt contains the data).

---

Depending on which programming language you are using, there are libraries either built on this dataset or on others.

See, for example, [gender-guesser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gender-guesser/), a python library ([github](https://github.com/lead-ratings/gender-guesser)) based on the above file (formerly called "sex machine").

```
>>> import gender_guesser.detector as gender
>>> d = gender.Detector()
>>> print(d.get_gender(u"Bob"))
male
>>> print(d.get_gender(u"Sally"))
female
>>> print(d.get_gender(u"Pauley")) # should be androgynous
andy
```

You can also specify country:

```
>>> print(d.get_gender(u"Jamie"))
mostly_female
>>> print(d.get_gender(u"Jamie", u'great_britain'))
mostly_male
```

That codes doesn't give JSON/XML, but it parses the raw `.txt` file from above into a python object. Probably you can hack `detector.py` to give you all names as JSON.

This is just one port of the raw data. I'm sure there are others.