# List of surnames of popular people in English

Tags: data-request, names

My question is similar to [this one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/46/8372). The difference is that I do not care about the ordinary people. All I need is a list of famous:

- scientists/inventors
- artists/musicians/authors
- politicians
- actors/actress/singers
- businessman/leaders
- sportsman
- explorers
- some other famous people whom I forgot

The person should not be from US/UK, but his surname should be written in English (Dostoevsky, Mahatma)

Comment: An idea: use wikipedia or wikidata since only fairly "popular" people would have an entry

Comment: Just as a note, I don't think "Mahatma" is a surname, or even a given name. It's more of a nickname (given to Gandhi for example). Just out of curiosity, do you feel the distribution of famous surnames will be significantly different from the distribution of all surnames? Or is that what you're testing?