# Data on ethnicity of African names

Tags: data-request, demographics, names, africa

Is there any data that lists the first/last name along with the dominant ethnicity associated with the name? I'm mostly interested in Africa.

Comment: if you can manage with first names per country, then check out this answer https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5003/1511

Answer (score 2):

I guess something like that would have to be computed from micro-data, prior to anonymization. Ideal would be censuses, but they are always conducted by the local statistical agencies and anonymized prior to being published and there's very limited international co-operation between these agencies. So chances that someone has already compiled such data are slim.

Organisations conducting large-scale international surveys, e.g., [afrobarometer](http://www.afrobarometer.org), MICS, or [DHS](https://www.dhsprogram.com/What-We-Do/Survey-Types/DHS.cfm), in principle have the necessary data and could compute what you're asking for. But you'd have to contact them to see whether they are willing and able to publicize a collapsed version of their raw data, only showing ethnicity shares by last names.

I myself have such data for The Gambia only, but I can not share it online. If still required send me an email.