# Data on percentage of name in the UK and US

Tags: usa, uk, names

Where could I find datasets of the percentage of name in the UK and US? I am looking at both first name and surname. And is it even possible to find such dataset?

Comment: For given names, see this question and its answers: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/46/multinational-list-of-popular-first-names-and-surnames?rq=1

Comment: For first names of USA citizens (19th Century until 2014) see https://github.com/hadley/babynames - and the many R tutorials associated with this dataset

Comment: Do you want just teh two lists, or do want correlations between the two?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to get correlation among the two, it looks too private information. So separated is fine for me.

Comment: @knb Awesome, thanks, Hadley is definitely an incredible guy.

Comment: And it's a good idea to do a package with these informations.