# Data source for names demography analysis?

Tags: data-request, demographics, names

I'm looking for datasets allowing one to map names (given names, family names) to geographical locations. So far, the best source I've found is Wiki/DBpedia with ~ 1 million records, and Web Of Science Author names and geolocation of their affiliation.

Is there any other source I could use or someone can think of?

Comment: Please look at [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/46/multinational-list-of-popular-first-names-and-surnames) and other question with the [tag:names] tag.

Answer (score 3):

The Dutch Central Bureau for Genealogy has an interface where you can type a family name and it will show the geographical distribution of that name throughout the Netherlands. You can also enter a single letter and search for names containing that letter, so with some scraping you should be able to get quite a bit of data. You can find the search interface here: 
http://www.cbgfamilienamen.nl/nfb/index.php?taal=eng

Comment: A similar service for Germany is http://www.verwandt.de

Answer (score 2):

The Social Security Administration in the U.S. publishes state-level baby names data since 1910. You could do a state-to-state comparison.

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/baby-names-from-social-security-card-applications-data-by-state-and-district-of-

Answer (score -1):

Check public telephone listings with adresses.