# Human name country wise corpus

Tags: uses-of-open-data, corpora, names

Where I can get the human name corpus country-wise, so that I can use it for training my neural network for detecting the human names out of the string.
Does anyone have idea of this?

Comment: First and/or last names? Please [edit]

Comment: Both ... if there is any corpus available then it will be ideal for my case

Comment: Wikidata/DBpedia? How many records do you need? In English only?

Comment: @StanislavKralin As many as I can get. There is no limit to the data. As the training needs more and more data.. say in GBs or TBs. So there is no question of any number of records. If you know many records, you just can tell me from where to get it.

Comment: Well, Wikidata contains about 3 millions of people... [This query](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Popular_surnames_among_humans) clarifies the structure of the data. Most likely, you need to download a (partial) dump to extract all these records.

Comment: I think this will help.. can you show me how I can get the complete database instead of the partial one.. please?

Comment: See also other questions with the [tag:names] tag. From [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7860/16193): [Fake Name Generator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multinational list of popular first names and surnames?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/46/multinational-list-of-popular-first-names-and-surnames)

Comment: @jknappen That question does not seem to be a duplicate. It is for separate lists, while this one is for the name combination.

Comment: Related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13116/recent-dump-of-names-from-facebook-com-directory

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Had you visited your suggestion first. The page is not found in the reference you have shared. So has no meaning to sharing.

Answer (score 1):

UK first names are available from birth registration data from the ONS [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/livebirths/bulletins/babynamesenglandandwales/previousReleases) (annual files are available and there is also data going back a lot of years). Trends and visualisation of some of this data are available on my [Tableau Public page](https://public.tableau.com/views/EnglandWalesbabynames/titlepage?:embed=y&:display_count=yes).

Data from the USA are also available. A good place to start is [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=baby-names). This dataset is also accessible from several other sources including an open dataset in [Google's BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sample-tables) (if you have an account then it saves a lot of downloading and structuring).

These generally only give the prevalence of first names for privacy reasons, but that is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2014 the Dutch social insurance bank publishes lists of most popular boys and girls names:

for boys: http://svbvod.download.kpnstreaming.nl/kindernamen-2016/jongens-populair-2016.pdf
for girls: http://svbvod.download.kpnstreaming.nl/kindernamen-2016/meisjes-populair-2016.pdf

For 2014 or 2015, change the years in the links.

Another source is a research institute in the Netherlands that keeps track of every single name in the Netherlands, in 2010 they published every first name that occurs more than 500 times in the Netherlands: http://www.meertens.knaw.nl/nvb/downloads/Top_eerste_voornamen_NL_2010.zip
They also have an interface which allows you to view the occurrence of names, but you can't use it to download bulk data: http://www.meertens.knaw.nl/nvb/english