# Recent dump of names from facebook.com/directory?

Tags: nlp, language, social-media, names, security

For years all names of all Facebook users were listed at
https://www.facebook.com/directory.

Even without the links to the profiles themselves, it was a very useful dataset of diverse names and versions of the same name around the world.

In 2010 a security researcher [scraped it](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2010/return-of-the-facebook) and made it [available as a torrent](http://academictorrents.com/details/e54c73099d291605e7579b90838c2cd86a8e957).

> 171 million names (100 million unique) ... limitation is that these are only users whose first characters are from the latin charset.

It grew significantly in size and diversity between 2010 and 2018, when it was deleted (*This page isn't available*) without warning, presumably in connection with political issues around user data.

Is there a relatively recent version available?  It could be incomplete if randomly sampled.

Comment: Related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/46/multinational-list-of-popular-first-names-and-surnames

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears all of archive.org's copies just consist of a captcha

Comment: @BarryCarter WAI, from some perspective.

Comment: Related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11505/human-name-country-wise-corpus