# Is there a large database of unique surnames and their (origin) language?

Tags: data-request, language, global, names

Let me explain the phrases I use in my request:

> **large:** I'm looking for multiple languages (especially european languages if this constrain helps) and at least 2K surnames per language. But the more the better.
>
> **database:** I expect that there is somewhere a machine readable file (json, txt, xml, ...) with all the names and languages or a zip file with many such files.
>
> **unique:** I'm not interested in how popular a surname is, I'm just interested in which surnames belong to a given language. Also variants of names are welcome.
>
> **surnames:** I want surnames or what comes closest to a surname in the language the name comes from.
>
> **(origin) language:** Even though there are many german speaking people named "Nguyen" this name shall not be classified as "german" but as "vietnamese".

I already looked at several places and found the following unsatisfying results:

- [Multinational list of popular first names and surnames?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/46/multinational-list-of-popular-first-names-and-surnames): This question is a good starting point but it aims for the popularity of names and the answers are more about first names. Also because it's about the popularity of names it is about where names are being used instead of where they come from.
- [heise.de](ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ct/listings/0717-182.zip): From the answers of the aforementioned question I got this list of first names which is pretty close to what I want - but these are first names not surnames.
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_most_common_surnames): These lists are way too short but I like that the names are broken down to countries.
- [Namespedia](http://de.namespedia.com/): This site seems to have a large database of surnames but I can't access them easily. I would have to write a crawler to go through the entire website.

Is there a database that meets all my requirements?